# Polymorphism in C++

Tags: c++

this is my code:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream> 
#include <cstring>  
using namespace std;

class person {
string name;
public:

    person(const string &n){
        name=n;
    }   
    virtual person& print(const person&){}   
};

class worker:public person {
    int number;
public:
    worker(const string &n , int num ):person(n){
        number=num;
    }

    virtual worker& print(const worker& x){
        cout << number << x.number<< endl; 
        return number+=number;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    person *p = new worker("john",1);
    person *g = new worker("jack",2);
    int c = p->print(*g);

    return 0;
}
```

All workers are persons, but not all persons are workers. Worker is child class of person. My problem is with print method. I dont know how to properly design relation between classes.

In this code result will be empty because main function calls print method of person class.
What i need is to use polymorphism to call method print of worker.

I could use this:

```
virtual worker& print(const person& x){
        cout << number << x.number<< endl; 
    }
```

Code above calls the right method but there is no number attribute in person class. So this wont work either.

Can anyone help me how to properly design my program ? I need to call print function on ancestor class so it would redirect call to right class. This is very simplified example, there are more child-classes so it needs to stay in relation person > worker .

Thank anyone for help.

Comment: This is known as double dispatch -- polymorphism on two objects at once.

Comment: What would you want to happen if the print function of a `person` object is called with a `worker` object as an argument, or vice versa?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have already noticed, a method in the parent class cannot see the members that are defined only in its subclass. If you think about this for a moment, it makes a lot of sense, because the parent cannot possibly know about how of its possible subclasses at the time of its compilation, so how could it know about their new data members?

The correct way to do this is to make the `print()` method in `Person` class **pure virtual**, and write a separate `print()` method for each subclass, because only the subclasses have access to their private data members.

```
virtual void print() = 0;
```

Notice that the function no longer takes a parameter, and its implementation in subclasses should print their own `number` and whichever other members they would like to print.

Comment: I don't see how this helps his situation. It will just result in compiler errors because he can't instantiate the worker class, unless you suggest a change to that also.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley, Look at the text of the answer. I asked him to write a separate `print()` for each subclass.

Comment: And what signature do you suggest he gives it? He's already written a print function for the subclass. The problem is that it has the wrong signature, and so does not participate in dynamic dispatch. But if he gives it the right signature (taking a `person` instead of a `worker` as an argument), the function won't compile because it accesses members which the `person` class does not have.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley, Very good points. I have updated the answer. I think the reason he accepted the original answer was because he was looking for ideas about how to design it, rather than specific code, which admitedly did not solve the problem. I was too hasty when writing this answer. :(

Answer (score 1):

This code is just bizarre. To print, you don't need to pass in a `person` or a `worker`.

```
class person
{
     public: virtual void print(){ cout << name; }
};

class worker : public person
{
     public: virtual void print(){ person::print(); cout << ": " << number; }
};

int main()
{
     person *p = new worker( "john", 1 ),
            *q = new worker( "jack", 2 );
     p->print();
     q->print();

     return 0;
}
```

Comment: OP wants to print based on argument to print()

Answer (score 1):

Your two `print` functions differ both in return and in parameter type. So they don't have anything in common but the name. Additionally, at runtime the computer doesn't know which "kind" of `Person` `p` and `q` are pointing to. Therefore you need to give `print` a uniform signature, e.g.:

```
class Person
{
public:
    virtual int print(Person* other) {}
}
```

I assumed you wanted `print` to return an `int` since you wrote `int c = p->print(*g);`. Also I used a pointer to use variable types as arguments. In `Worker` - and other derived classes - you can write something like this:

```
int print(Person* other)
{
    Worker* worker = dynamic_cast<Worker*>(other);
    if (worker)
    {
        std::cout << number << " " << worker->number << std::endl;
        return number += worker->number;
    }
    else
    {
        // return default value and/or make some output that cast failed
        return -1;
    }
}
```

To avoid the `dynamic_cast` operator which uses *RTTI* (Runtime Type Information) what is **not recommended** you can introduce an enumeration in `Person` that holds the type of the derived class:

```
class Person
{
protected: 
    enum EPersonType {WORKER /*insert other derivats here*/};
    const EPersonType Type;

    Person(EPersonType type) : Type(type) {}
    virtual int printDetails(Person* other) {}

public:
    int print(Person* other)
    {
        if (other->Type != Type)
            return -1;
        else 
            return printDetails(other);       // you can now use safe cast inhere
    }
}

class Worker : public Person
{
public:
    Worker() : Person(WORKER) {}
    int printDetails(Person* other)
    {
        Worker* worker = static_cast<Worker*>(other);  // always works
                                                       // also possible: ...= (Worker*)other;
        //...
    } 
}
```